# MySQL: nothing listening on port 3306 but the processes still exist. How to graceful shutdown?

Tags: mysql, kill, kill-process

- Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-server-5.5.24-23.6.340.rhel5

This is a slave server. `mysqladmin shutdown` hangs at:

```
[Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 24 events 
[Note] Slave I/O thread killed while reading event 
[Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.000878', position 848536790
```

so, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and the terminal show the below warning:

```
Warning;  Aborted waiting on pid file: '/var/lib/mysql/x.pid' after 302 seconds
```

The processes still exist:

`root      9623     1  0 10:18 pts/8    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/x.pid`

`mysql    10357  9623  0 10:18 pts/8    00:00:06 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --open-files-limit=100000 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/x.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

but the socket file is missing:

```
ls: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock: No such file or directory
```

and there is nothing listening on port 3306.

```
# netstat --inet -nlp | grep :3306
# lsof -i :3306
#
```

Sending a SIGTERM signal (`kill -15`) to the child process doesn't work. What can I do but `kill -9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing.  Get out the SIGKILL bat and prepare for a log recovery.

Comment: There is only a few processes when stopping. How many minutes should I wait before pressing Ctrl-C?

Comment: You should never press Ctrl-C.  Who runs MySQL servers in the foreground?

Comment: MySQL server was started by init script. It happened to me that [InnoDB couldn't recover](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21146/mysql-innodb-keeps-crashing-how-to-recover) after doing a `kill -9`.